# How to use string format using "{0.word}"

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, formatting

I've been reading through section 6 of the Python Standard Library.  I've come to the following point of string formatting:

```
"Weight in tons {0.weight}"      # 'weight' attribute of first positional arg
```

I don't understand what to place in the `.format` brackets to replace `weight` with a weight.  If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

As an attempt I tried the following, but it failed:

```
"Weight in tons {0.weight}".format({'weight':10})
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'weight'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That syntax is for attributes, not keys. If you want to print an element from a dictionary, then use:

```
print("Weight in tons {0[weight]}".format({'weight':10}))
```

Here is a valid use of the `.` syntax:

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = 10

d = Dummy()
print("Weight in tons {0.weight}".format(d))
```

Finally, instead of this:

```
"Weight in tons {0.weight}".format({'weight':10})
```

...you might have meant to use the named arguments syntax:

```
print("Weight in tons {weight}".format(weight=10))
```

Comment: and I think that it's clearer to do `'weight in tons {weight}'.format(weight=10)`

Comment: FWIW, the failed attempt in the question is similar to this usage of the old string formatting syntax: `"Weight in tons %(weight)s" % {'weight':10}`

Answer (score 5):

Its better to unpack the dictionary like this

```
"Weight in tons {weight}".format(**{'weight':10})
# Weight in tons 10
```

So that you can simply access the values with their corresponding key names, like this, `{weight}`.